# Problem with adding tags to ffmpeg m3u8 file

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming, m3u8

i tried to generate a hls file in ffmpeg and here is the result:

#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=400400,RESOLUTION=284x160,CODECS="avc1.64000c,mp4a.40.2"
160p/index.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=875600,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.64001e,mp4a.40.2"
360p/index.m3u8

but i need to add a custom header tag like "Name" to it

here is my desired export:

#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=400400,RESOLUTION=284x160,Name="160p",CODECS="avc1.64000c,mp4a.40.2"
160p/index.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=875600,RESOLUTION=640x360,Name="360p",CODECS="avc1.64001e,mp4a.40.2"
360p/index.m3u8

how can i do that? Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I checked the latest release's (4.3.2) source code ([libavformat/hlsplaylist.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n4.3.2/libavformat/hlsplaylist.c#L83)) and it looks like you cannot add a "Name" attribute to EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag.